# What functors are classified by slices of $\infty$-categories?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, infinity-categories, slice-categories

Suppose I have a functor $f\colon C\to D$ between $\infty$-categories (I'll assume $C$ and $D$ are small.)  Then I can form the *slice categories* and *restriction functors*
$$
D_{f/}\to D\qquad \text{and} \qquad D_{/f}\to D.
$$
These maps are *left fibrations* and *right fibrations*, respectively.  By the theory of "straightening/unstraightening", these fibrations are classified by certain functors
$$
D\to \mathcal{S} \qquad\text{and} \qquad D^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathcal{S}
$$
to the $\infty$-category $\mathcal{S}$ of $\infty$-groupoids.  This raises the question:

**Q.  What are these functors?**

Actually, it's pretty clear what the answer should be:

**A.  They are inverse limits of (co)representable functors.**

Explicitly, we should be able to describe these functors by

$$
d\mapsto \mathrm{lim}_{c\in C^{\mathrm{op}}}\operatorname{Map}_D(f(c),d)
\qquad \text{and}\qquad
d\mapsto \mathrm{lim}_{c\in C}\operatorname{Map}_D(d,f(c))
$$
respectively.  In the 1-categorical analogue this an elementary argument.  The case of $C=1$ (slices over objects, corresponding to (co)representable functors) is "well-known" (see 5.8 of Cisinski's *Higher categories and homotopical algebra*).

So my real question is:

**Q'.  What is a proof or reference for this fact?**

Comment: This approach is used by Riehl and Verity in their $\infty$-cosmoi, so it may be worth looking in their [Elements of $\infty$-categories](https://math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/elements.pdf), section 3.5.

Comment: Since you asked for reference, I would say that Prop. 6.1.14 in my book, together with the fact that the terminal presheaf is the colimit of the Yoneda embedding (Cor. 6.2.16) are relevant (this is closely related to Maxime's answer, of course).

Answer (score 13):

Here's a sketch of a proof :

> Lemma: For a left fibration $p: A\to B$, the functor it classifies $B\to \mathcal S$ is given by $p_!(*)$, where $p_! : Fun(A,\mathcal S)\to Fun(B,\mathcal S)$ is left Kan extension.

Proof: Note that $Fun(A,\mathcal S)$ is equivalent to the full subcategory of $Cat_\infty/A$ on left fibrations, similarly for $B$, and the pullback functor $p^*: Cat_\infty/B\to Cat_\infty/A$ restricts to the precomposition functor on functor categories. But the left adjoint to $p^*$ on these slice categories is postcomposition by $p$, and the full subcategories on left fibrations are stable under this postcomposition because $p$ is itself a left fibration. It follows that $p_!$ is given by postcomposition at the level of fibrations.

Moreover, the constant $*$-valued functor on $A$ classifies $A\to A$, so that postcomposition by $p$ sends this to $A\to B$, so $p_!(*)$ is the image of that functor.

> $D_{f/}$ classifies the functor you suggested.

Proof: Apply the lemma to $p: D_{f/}\to D$, to get that the classified functor is $p_!(*)$. On objects, this is given by $d\mapsto \mathrm{colim}_{(D_{f/})_{/d}}*$.

Now the $\infty$-category $(D_{f/})_{/d}$ is weakly equivalent to the mapping space $map(f,\Delta(d))$ in $Fun(C,D)$, so this colimit is given by this mapping space, which can be described by your limit.

The case of right fibrations is dual.

ADDED later : maybe it'd be good to have an argument for my weak equivalence claim. $\{id_d\}\to D_{/d}$ is cofinal, and $D_{f/}\to D$ is a left fibration, so pullback along it preserves cofinality (4.4.11. in Cisinski's book, although he uses "final" for what I call "cofinal"), in particular the fiber of $D_{f/}\to D$ over $\{id_d\}$ (the mapping space I mentioned) is cofinal in the pullback $(D_{f/})_{/d}$, which of course implies the claim about weak equivalence.

EDIT 2 : Here's how to see from the above paragraph that this is actually a functorial description: $\{id_d\}\to D_{/d}$ is lax natural in $d$, and therefore so is $(D_{f/})_{/d}\times_{D_{/d}} \{id_d\}\to (D_{f/})_{/d}$.

Now, the claim was that this second map is cofinal, so in particular, it induces an equivalence (which is of course still natural in $d$) between the "geometric realizations" (I'm not sure anymore what the standard name is for the left adjoint $Cat_\infty\to\mathcal S$); and on geometric realizations we can change from "lax natural" to "natural". Moreover, almost by definition, the LHS of this map is $map(f,\Delta(d))$ *as a functor* of $d$, not just pointwise.

The final claim is, of course, that $\mathrm{colim}_A *$ is the weak homotopy type of $A$, again naturally in $A$.

Comment: Thanks, that's an excellent lemma.

Comment: It's not apparent from the way I phrased the question, but I want to identify the *functor* $D\to \mathcal{S}$ itself as a limit of corepresentables, not mere identify its values.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @CharlesRezk : yes, I think so - that's why I added the later part : you have a natural (in $d$) map $map(f,\Delta(d)) \to (D_{f/})_{/d}$ which happens to be cofinal and thus an equivalence on colimits

Comment: Perhaps more precisely : the formula for Kan extensions is functorial, the setup for this is somewhere in HTT, but that's enough

Comment: I've added a few words about that in the answer !

Answer (score 5):

I like Maxime's argument better, but here's another.

As you say, the case when $C=\bullet$ is well-known. But we can reduce to that case! The map $D_{/f} \to D$ is pulled back from $\mathsf{Fun}(C, D)_{/f} \to \mathsf{Fun}(C,D)$ along the diagonal map $D \to \mathsf{Fun}(C,D)$. Under (un)straightening, pulling back corresponds to precomposition, and the functor on $\mathsf{Fun}(C,D)$ represented by $f$ restricts to the functor you described.

Comment: This is nice!  To make things clear: the "pullback" describing $D_{/f}$ is an on-the-nose pullback in simplicial sets if you use "alternate slice" in place of slice.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{S}$ denote the $\infty$-category of small spaces. For a small $\infty$-category $A$ and its object $a\in A$, I will write $A(-,a):A^\mathrm{op}\to\mathcal{S}$ for the presheaf represented by $a$. I will also write $\widehat{\mathcal{S}}$ for the $\infty$-category of large spaces.

As Dylan points out, we have $C^{/f}\cong C\times_{\operatorname{Fun}(C,D)}\operatorname{Fun}(C,D)^{/f}$. So the right fibration $C^{/f}\to C$ classifies the functor $\operatorname{Fun}(C,D)(\delta-,f):D^\mathrm{op}\to\mathcal{S}$, where $\delta:D \to \operatorname{Fun}(C,D)$ is the diagonal embedding. I claim that this functor is the limit of the diagram $$C\xrightarrow{f}D\xrightarrow{j}\mathcal{P}(D)=\operatorname{Fun}(D^\mathrm{op},\mathcal{S}),$$

where $j$ is the Yoneda embedding. Let $F\in\mathcal{P}(D)$ denote the limit of this diagram. It is characterized by the natural equivalence $$\mathcal{P}(D)(-,F)\simeq \operatorname{Fun}(C,\mathcal{P}(D))(\delta -,jf)$$
of functors $\mathcal{P}(D)^\mathrm{op}\to\widehat{\mathcal{S}}$. Restricting this along the Yoneda embedding and using the Yoneda lemma, we obtain a natural equivalence
$$F\simeq\operatorname{Fun}(C,D)(\delta-,f)$$ as required.